# Good resources for Winforms development

Tags: winforms, user-controls, resources

What are some good resources for winforms development?

For example, when you have to have a bunch of different controls and event handlers on one form. Do you use partial classes, user controls, special attributes,...?

How do you handle communication between user controls - only with events?

Are there any patterns you can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windowsclient.net/ is a good start. When we do winform development at work we use a MVP type of pattern and try and minimize the code behind. For user controls to communicate you can do events or implement a mediator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for design techniques for your forms inner architecture, you may find ["The humble dialog box"](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf) from Michael Feathers helpful. Not specific for WinForms, of course, but a general suggestion how to separate the logic from the layout to make your code better testable.

If you are looking for a WinForms book, there is [the book from Charles Petzold](http://books.google.com/books?id=mRh0QgAACAAJ&dq=c%23+programming+petzold&hl=de&ei=FdFXTIr3BNShOJCtxPoI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA). It is a little bit outdated (still .NET 1.1, AFAIK), but I don't know any better book about WinForms.